# Closed linear span in a Hilbert space defined as the sums of unconditionally convergent series

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space over complex numbers and let $U \subset H$.

Then, the closed linear span of $U$ is defined as $$T = \left\{ \sum_{u \in U} c_n u \mid  c_n \text{ complex } , \sum_{u \in U} c_n u  \text{ converges unconditionally} \right\}.$$

But, how do I see that this set is closed?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't necessarily closed. For example consider $H=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ and $U=\{e_1-e_2,e_2-e_3,...\}$ (denote from now on $e_k-e_{k+1}$ by $u_k$).

You have that $e_1$ lies in the closure of the linear span, since it is the limit
$$e_1=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{N-n+1}N\ u_n$$
 but *not* in the "closed linear span" as it is defined here. To see that suppose $e_1=\sum_n c_n u_n$ where the sum converges (a weaker condition than unconditional convergence!), from continuity of the scalar product you get (with $k\neq1$):
$$1=\langle e_1,\sum_n c_n\,u_n\rangle=\sum_nc_n\langle e_1,u_n\rangle=c_1\\
0=\langle e_k,\sum_nc_n u_n\rangle=\sum_nc_n\langle e_k,u_n\rangle=c_{k}-c_{k-1}$$
It follows from induction $c_k=1$ for all $k$. So:
$$\|e_1-\sum_n^N u_n\|=\|-e_{N+1}\|=1$$
and the sum doesn't converge to $e_1$!